# How to use dart-lang/markdown to show a paragraph?

Tags: dart, flutter, markdown, dart-pub

I'm new to flutter, and I want to show a paragraph(markdown text) in my app page.

But I'm confused how to use it. I didn't find a widget in dart-lang/markdown.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/markdown

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_markdown